# Calling Informix Stored Procedure from SQL Lite

Tags: sqlite, informix

We have a informix database with stored procedure named LicenseTotals()
We have a quicker version to run the software using SQL Lite. However, the query below throws error when SQL Lite is used.

```
SELECT name,value FROM TABLE( FUNCTION LicenseTotals()) (pkid,name,value,UserValue,DeviceValue)
```

Below is the error I get;

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): 
SQL logic error or missing database near "TABLE": syntax error
```

Comment: Does [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) document support for that notation?  Probably not (I can't see it in the linked document), hence the error message.  You'll have to work out what the equivalent SQLite notation is, if there is one.  It isn't automatically a given that you can use the results of a function as a table in SQLite.

Comment: Actually, looking at [Query Language Understood by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html), I don't see support for user defined functions; I've not looked into the API support, but you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports (scalar) [user-defined functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), and [virtual tables](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html), but not stored procedures.

You should have noticed this when your attempt to create the stored procedure failed.